# Not able to open PHP webapp in local Apache server. Get Error 404

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to start working with a PHP webapp (written by someone else) on a local Apache server. Every time I try to open any .php file in the project folder, I get error 404.

I checked that the server is working by opening other php files in other projects, no problems there. After researching possible causes, I suspect that it might be the `.htaccess` file but I'm not sure what is the specific problem. The code in this file is the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ^http$
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    Options -Multiviews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^cache/(.*)/images/(.*) /images/$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^cache/(.*)/fonts/(.*) /fonts/$2 [L]        
    RewriteRule ^(sitemap.xml|sitemap_xml/*) - [L]
    RewriteRule ^(robots.txt|robots_txt/*) - [L]
    RewriteRule ^(sitemap.php|sitemap.php/*) - [L]
    RewriteRule ^(sitemap-dom.php|sitemap-dom.php/*) - [L]
        RewriteRule ^about-us /cms/view/about-us/1
        RewriteRule ^contact-us /cms/view/contact-us/24
        RewriteRule ^privacy-policy /cms/view/privacy-policy/21
        RewriteRule ^terms-and-conditions /cms/view/terms-and-conditions/20
        RewriteRule ^how-it-works /cms/view/how-it-works/18
        RewriteRule ^faq /cms/faq
    RewriteRule    ^$ public/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L,QSA]
 </IfModule>
```

Is this restricting any access to files in the project's directory?

I'm just starting to work with this so any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the information provided you can check the following hypotesis:

Are you running apache with https?

On folder `sites-enabled` in your apache, check if the ssl virtualhost is enabled.

If not running, probably the `.htaccess` file are redirecting to `https`, while, runs on `443` port, the lines 2 and 3 are redirecting all http requests to https requests.

If you want to check, you can use telnet. I've tried locally on port 80 (apache defaut) to see what happens:

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

The default behavior if running is above. To cal telnet command, we use `telnet <address> <port>`. If telnet stays without response for a minute, it seems that your port are not listening

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 443
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable
```

Now, I tried to connect in my apache with ssl disabled (443 is the default SSL port), so, the error listed above has been returned. In this case, my `000-default-ssl.conf` file are disabled

To enable your ssl configuration you can run `a2ensite 000-defaul-ssl.conf`, where  `000-default-ssl.conf` is my ssl default file in `sites-available` folder.